# Norms for a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

How can I give two non-equivalent norms to a infinite dimensional vector space with infinite Hamel basis?

Comment: Consider the vector space of real polynomials, with the $p$-norm, for different values of $p$.

Comment: Do you want an example of this, or do you want to prove it is true for all infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: I want actually both.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|_1)$ be an infinite dimensional normed space. One can show that there exists a [discontinuous linear functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map), say $L$. Now set $$\|x\|_2 := \|x\|_1 + |L(x)|.$$ Notice that there is no constant $c$ such that $\|x\|_2 \le c\|x\|_1$, since this would imply $|L(x)|\le (c - 1)\|x\|_1$, a contradiction to the assumption that $L$ is not continuous.